# redux error on the property 'type' while using middlewares

Tags: redux, redux-middleware

I'm trying to integrate a logger in my redux app, using the applyMiddleware api, but when I trigger an action I got this error:

*Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?*

This is strange because all of my action creators returns objects with this format:
`{ type : ..., payload : {...}}`. And more, in the console of the browser the printed object **has** the property 'type'.

I set up the store in this way:

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
    console.log(action);
    return next(store, action);
}

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(logger));

export default store;
```

I got stuck.

Comment: Instead of `next(store, action);` try `next(action);`

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm sorry, that was elementary :(